# Ruby how to print/puts read file contents instead of a bunch of numbers/symbols

Tags: arrays, ruby, file, class, file-handling

In ruby I have created a class and array, to read the contents from a text file then output them.

```
class Album
    attr_accessor :artist, :title, :genre, :tracks
end
album = Album.new(album_title, album_artist, album_genre, tracks)
```

-> tracks is an array of multiple lines read from the text file using a while loop. Context below, a_file/music_file File.new("album.txt", "r")

```
class Track
  attr_accessor :name, :location

  def read_track(a_file)
    track_title = a_file.gets()
    track_location = a_file.gets()
    track = Track.new(track_title, track_location)
  end

  def read_tracks(music_file)
    tracks = Array.new()
    count = music_file.gets().to_i()
    track = music_file
    index = 0
    while (index < count)
        track = read_track(music_file)
        tracks << track
        index += 1
    end
    return tracks
  end
end
```

after `album = Album.new(album_title, album_artist, album_genre, tracks)`, I passed the album to a different procedure `print_tracks(album)`, and in `print_tracks(album)`, I have `puts album.tracks`.

But instead of printing out several lines of track names and track locations, I get something that looks like this:

```
#<Track:0x000055c028027b08>
#<Track:0x000055c0280277c0>
#<Track:0x000055c028027630>
```

How do I print out the actual words on the file?

Comment: How do you print out the tracks? How does that code look like? When you want the output to have a specific format, for example, to include name and location then you have to tell Ruby the desired format. Did you declare a custom `to_s` or `inspect` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are getting in return are instances of your Track class. Each of those instances has access to attributes like name and location as specified under the class definition in attr_accessor. You can change your last statement (`return tracks`) (take note that `return` here is not needed since its the last statement in the method, the last thing will be returned by default in ruby).

Try this instead of `return tracks`

```rb
tracks.map{ |track| {track_name: track.name, track_location: track.location} }
```

This was you will end up with array of hashes with keys of **track_name** and **track_location** each containing a value of one track. I am not sure what kind of format you want to return, but this is a rather simple, yet flexible. The most simplistic way would be array of array, which you can get using:

```rb
racks.map{ |track| [track.name, track.location] }
```

Comment: tracks.map{ |track| [track.name, track.location] } had the effect I wanted thank you. Though I also found I could call a procedure with "puts track.name" "puts track.location" and loop it based on the length of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You're observing the default behavior defined in [`Object#to_s`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-to_s) and [`Object#inspect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-inspect).

Ruby uses the `to_s` method to convert objects to strings and the `inspect` method to obtain string representations of objects suitable for debugging. By default, `to_s` and `inspect` are more or less the same thing. The only difference is `inspect` will also show the instance variables.

You can and should override these methods in your `Track` class. For example:

```
class Track
  def to_s
    "#{self.class.name} #{name} @ {location}"
  end

  def inspect
    "#<#{to_s}>"
  end
end

track.to_s
puts track
# Track: name @ /music/name.flac

track.inspect
p track
# #<Track: name @ /music/name.flac>
```